# Join in neo4j on a common id from two group of labels by creating relationship

Tags: neo4j

I have two group of nodes, :Contact and :GroupMember having `ContactId` in common. How can I join these two group of nodes and get the results of contacts who belong to a `GroupId` by creating a relationship between them?

- :Contact - Name, EmailId, ContactId
- :GroupMember - ContactId, GroupId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
MATCH (c:Contact),(g:GroupMember) where c.ContactId = g.ContactId
CREATE (g)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->(c)
```

Comment: @Vybhavi_Rs Also, it will help to have indexes on both :Contact(ContactId) and :GroupMember(ContactId), and to remove the `ContactId` property from :GroupMember after the relationship is created (as well as deleting the index on :GroupMember(ContactId)), since you won't have any need for these when the relationship is in place.